# Gmock to test function that returns structure

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock function that returns structure. But I get below problem

==> error: use of deleted function

```
class MockTest: public TestInterface
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(func1, struct Response(std::string const &serviceName));
};

TEST_F (Test_1, Start)
{
    struct Response Obj;
    Obj.var = 5;

    EXPECT_CALL(*Mockpointer, func1(_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(Return(Obj)); /*Compiler throws error here [error: use of deleted function]*/

    auto result = FileToTest_Obj->start(); /*please Assume start function is under test*/
    EXPECT_EQ(true, result);
}

Code snippet for reference.
bool start()
{
    struct Response response = func1(serviceName);
    if(5 == response.var ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there something I am missing. Is there any sample examples I can refer to mock the function that returns structure

Comment: Google Mock probably requires a copy constructor or assignment operator for `struct Response`.

Comment: Thank you rveerd, yes I guess you pointed out correct.
In my environment, struct Response is declared in third party library, I am not allowed to change it.
Is there any work around in this case.

Comment: If it's moveable, try using `ByMove` (https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-methods-that-use-move_only-types)

Comment: Yes I can use ByMove but if the mock function is called 9 times, then ByMove logic will not work as the object is already moved during first mock call.

I read this heading(Mocking Methods That Use Move-Only Types), but still no luck
https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html